# Seeking Help for Solving a Trig System of Equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

This problem was given on an Algebra 2 practice test I took and I still don't understand it after several days of contemplation.

$3\sin(\frac{x}{2})-1 = x^3 -2x + 1$

Comment: This looks more like an equation that has to be solved numerically.

Comment: What is the question? Solve for x. OR Number of solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have explicit solutions to tanscendental equations (this is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$).

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=3 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1 - (x^3 -2x + 1)$$ If you plot it, you should notice a root close to $x=-2$ and two other around $x=1$.

For the first, let us make an expansion to get
$$f(x)=(2-3 \sin (1))+(x+2) \left(\frac{3 \cos (1)}{2}-10\right)+(x+2)^2
   \left(6+\frac{3 \sin (1)}{8}\right)+O\left((x+2)^3\right)$$ Using the first term only, you will have
$$x \sim -2+\frac{4-6 \sin (1)}{20-3 \cos (1)}\approx -2.05707$$ while the exact solution, obtained using Newton method, is $x=-2.05497$. Solving the quadratic would give
$x=-2.05499$.

For the two other do the same
$$f(x)=\left(3 \sin \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\right)+(x-1) \left(\frac{3}{2} \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\right)+(x-1)^2 \left(-3-\frac{3}{8} \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ Solve the quadratic to get $x=0.675172$ and $x=1.42432$ which are quite good approximations.